# How can a persistenceContext link with multiple EntityManager

Tags: entity, persistence, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

Recently I have gone through PRO JPA2 book and find that "A single `persistence context` can be link with multiple `EntityManager` instance."

I have searched for the same but could not found satisfactory answer. Can anybody elaborate this with example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what was meant without more context from the book.  That said, if you're using container-managed JPA within a global transaction, then each injected EntityManager referring to the same persistence unit will be backed by the same persistence context.  For example:

```
@Stateless
public class Bean {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em1;

    @EJB
    OtherBean otherBean;

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED) // The type, but for illustration
    public void doWork() {
        // ... use em1
        otherBean.doMoreWork();
    }
}

@Stateless
public class OtherBean {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em2;

    public void doMoreWork() {
        // ... use em2, it shares a persistence context with em1
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do we go about it, If we want one bean to have two entity managers ?

Comment: @valik It's probably best to start a second question referencing this one rather than commenting on a very old answer.